# Unable to create CmsSigner with private key on smart card

Tags: mimekit

I'm running into an error when I try to create a CmsSigner to sign my message.

Basically, I have several certs in my personal cert store with the same email address (subject), and when I use the ApplicationPkcs7Mime.Sign() method, it's using the wrong cert to sign my message.

Thus, in order to find the correct cert, I've basically implemented a search and initialise the correct CmsSigner to use for the signing. However, I'm running into an error which I suspect is because the private key to the corresponding cert is inside my smart card is non-exportable. Here is the code I've written and the error I get.

```
   X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection collection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, userEmail, true);
        MimeKit.Cryptography.CmsSigner signer = null;

        foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in collection)
        {             
            if (cert.Issuer.Contains("My_Trusted_CA") && cert.HasPrivateKey)
            {

                foreach (X509Extension ext in cert.Extensions)
                {
                    if (ext.Oid.FriendlyName == "Key Usage")
                    {

                        X509KeyUsageExtension keyUsage = (X509KeyUsageExtension)ext;
                        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyUsageFlags keyUsageFlags = keyUsage.KeyUsages;
                        if (keyUsageFlags.HasFlag(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature))
                        {
                            Log("Certificate Found: " + cert.SerialNumber);
                            try
                            {
                                signer = new MimeKit.Cryptography.CmsSigner(cert);
                            } catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                ThrowErrorMessage("Error creating CMS Signer: " + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the exception thrown:

```
Error creating CMS Signer: Invalid type specified.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._ExportKey(SafeKeyHandle hKey, Int32 blobType, Object cspObject)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters(Boolean includePrivateParameters)
   at MimeKit.Cryptography.AsymmetricAlgorithmExtensions.GetAsymmetricKeyParameters(RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa, Boolean publicOnly, AsymmetricKeyParameter& pub, AsymmetricKeyParameter& key)
   at MimeKit.Cryptography.AsymmetricAlgorithmExtensions.GetAsymmetricKeyParameter(RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa)
   at MimeKit.Cryptography.CmsSigner..ctor(X509Certificate2 certificate)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of .NET are you using?

Check to see if `MimeKit.Cryptography.WIndowsSecureMimeContext` is available to you (it should be available for >= .NET v4.5 as long as you reference the `net45` target for MimeKit in packages.config).

Assuming that's available to you, I would recommend subclassing `WindowsSecureMimeContext` and overriding the [GetCmsSigner](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MimeKit_Cryptography_WindowsSecureMimeContext_GetCmsSigner.htm) method.

Once you do that, you'll be able to more-or-less copy & paste your current logic for getting the correct CmsSigner into that, resulting in something like this:

```
protected override System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.CmsSigner GetCmsSigner (MailboxAddress mailbox, DigestAlgorithm digestAlgo)
{
    var store = new X509Store (StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open (OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    var collection = store.Certificates.Find (X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, userEmail, true);
    System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.CmsSigner signer = null;

    foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in collection)
    {             
        if (cert.Issuer.Contains("My_Trusted_CA") && cert.HasPrivateKey)
        {
            foreach (X509Extension ext in cert.Extensions)
            {
                if (ext.Oid.FriendlyName == "Key Usage")
                {
                    var keyUsage = (X509KeyUsageExtension)ext;
                    var keyUsageFlags = keyUsage.KeyUsages;

                    if (keyUsageFlags.HasFlag (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature))
                    {
                        Log("Certificate Found: " + cert.SerialNumber);
                        try
                        {
                            signer = new System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.CmsSigner(cert);
                        } catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            ThrowErrorMessage("Error creating CMS Signer: " + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```